# How to force every float (figure/table) in the appendix to be placed on a separate page

Tags: floats, appendices

How to force all floats (figure/table) in the appendix to be placed on separate pages.

I mean only all floats in appendix to be placed in one page each. Floats in the main text should not be affected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you start the appendix do  `\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}`

Comment: What happens if we set it up to zero?

Comment: @Sigur Then no floats get placed (unless they have `!` in their option which says to ignore constraints)  (until end of document or `\clearpage`) (when all constraints are ignored)

Comment: So in those cases all floats will printed together at the final page? For example, instead of 4 pages with 1 float each, we get the last page with 4 floats? I guessed that this is the desired result by OP.

Comment: @Sigur if they fit or you don't overload latex with a too many floats error.